# Can't validate a json with a schema using an external schema file

Tags: json, powershell, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

**My issue**

I need to validate a json file from a Json Schema.
I have a main schema and this schema should load an external schema file to validate some part of the json.

For different reasons I can't merge them. I do need 2 schema file.

I am using a **$ref** statement as proposed in this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-7.2&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5004831

but whatever I try I have this error:

> **Cannot parse the JSON schema.**

**What I need**

What is the right schema syntax to do this in my case.

**Test case**

I have this directories on my disk:

```
.
test.ps1
----/jsons
       params.json
----/schemas
       securities.json
       storages.json
```

I run validation from this pretty simple PowerShell (test.ps1):

```
# read json param
$testFile = Get-Content "./jsons/params.json" -Encoding UTF8 | convertfrom-json -Depth 50
$testee = $testFile.parameters | convertto-json

# read json schema
$schemasFile = (Get-ChildItem -Path "./schemas/storages.json").FullName

# test json from schema
$result = $testee | Test-Json -SchemaFile $schemasFile 

$result
```

My json (params.json):

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "storages": [
            {
                "comment": "Very important storage",
                "name": "fdlmsto",
                "securities": [
                    {
                        "comment": "Critical rule",
                        "kind": "MSI"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The main schema (storages.json):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
        "storages"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "storages": {
            "$id": "#/properties/storages",
            "type": "array",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "items": [
                {
                    "$id": "#/properties/storages/items",
                    "type": "object",
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "required": [
                        "name",
                        "comment"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "$ref": "#/schemas/securities.json",
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "$id": "#/properties/storages/items/properties/name"
                        },
                        "comment": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "$id": "#/properties/storages/items/properties/comment"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and the child schema (securities.json):

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
        "securities"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "securities": {
            "$id": "#/properties/securities",
            "type": "array",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "items": {
                "$id": "/properties/securities/items",
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "$id": "#/properties/securities/items/anyOf/0",
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalItems": false,
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "required": [
                            "kind",
                            "comment"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "comment": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "$id": "#/properties/securities/items/anyOf/0/properties/comment"
                            },
                            "kind": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "$id": "#/properties/securities/items/anyOf/0/properties/kind"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What I tested**

I tested several syntaxe for $ref:

#/schemas/securities.json

./schemas/securities.json

/schemas/securities.json

....

I also tried to set the schema in the repository of test.ps1

I checked that this is the securities section that don't work

Thank you

---

I edit the question to leave what worked for me:

Change storages.json like this:

```
  "properties": {
                "securities": {
                    "$ref": "securities1.json#/securities"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "comment": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
```

Change securities.json as:

```
{
    "securities": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
                "kind",
                "comment"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "comment": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "kind": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And of course I applied all changed suggested in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the powershell cmdlet is [powered by NJsonSchema](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/3d4e294262d2f2d7472ebd5d849b1b68fd6ef524/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/TestJsonCommand.cs#L12), which at this stage doesn't support JSON Schema draft 2020-12.

There are several issues I see.

#### *storages.json*

1. "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema" declares this is a draft 2020-12 schema.  As your schema doesn't use any 2020-12 features, I'd suggest using draft 7 as it'll definitely be supported by NJsonSchema.
2. Your schema is declaring itself to be the meta-schema with `"$id": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"`.  The meta-schema is a special schema that validates other schemas.  What you probably want here is just `storages.json`, or even better, a full URI like `https://examp.le/schemas/storages.json`.  It's just an identifier though; it doesn't need to be downloadable.
3. Remove the internal `$id`s.  They're only specifying relative location and not providing any more detail.  This kind of thing is generally calculated at runtime.
4. Your `$ref` is wrong.  `#/schemas/securities.json` is going to try to search for this location *inside* the current schema.  You need a full URI here, and you'll want to declare that same URI as `$id` in *securities.json* as well.  This may be what is producing the error.
5. At `#/properties/storages`, you have `"type": "array"` and `"additionalProperties": false`.  Maybe you meant `additionalItems`?  `additionalProperties` only works on objects.  (I also see this in *securities.json* at `#/properties/securities`.)
6. Your use of `items` is an array.  This will only validate the first item.  I think you're wanting to validate all the items.  If so, just use the schema as the value for `items`; don't wrap it in an array.  (also seen in *securities.json*)

#### *securities.json*

1. This schema uses draft 4, which is quite old and a bit incompatible with later drafts.  Specifically, I see it's using `$id` in several places, which replaced draft 4's `id` in draft 6.  Since draft 4 doesn't recognize `$id`, it'll probably ignore them.  Moreover, `$ref`-ing between drafts isn't something that's required (or perhaps even addressed) by the specification.  (I  added some tests to the test suite around this only about a week ago.)  As with *storages.json* I'd suggest using draft 7 here.
2. As mentioned above, you'll want to add an `$id` to the root so that the `$ref` in *storages.json* can identify this schema properly.
3. As with *storages.json*, remove the interal `$id`s; they're not providing any additional function.
4. You use an `anyOf` but only declare a single schema.  You don't need this.  Just move the keywords in that subschema up to where the `allOf` is.

   ```json
   {
     "type": "object",
     "allOf": [ { ... } ]
   }

   // becomes

   {
     "type": "object",
     ...
   }
   ```

Sorry this sounds like a pile-on.  I realize you might be new with JSON Schema.  The learning curve can be pretty steep.

Instead of the documentation provided by MS, I'd use [Understanding JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/) for how to write schemas.  Use the MS docs *only* for how to use the cmdlet.

Comment: I completed the solution to say what worked

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one point to the excellent answer above:  the array form of `items` is not valid in 2020-12 anyway - it was replaced with `prefixItems`.

But the advice to use draft-07 throughout is the right advice, as is the advice to use the schema form of `items` anyway.